# Merge sort output - scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, mergesort

I have a merge sort function that takes a predicate and a list of real values, it then sorts them according to the predicate. e.g.

```
(merge-sort > '(1 7 4 6)) 
    ---> (7 6 4 1)
```

My question is given the association lists:

```
(define *Mark*
    '( (age . 20)
       (gender . male))

(define *Judith*
    '( (age . 30)
       (gender . female))

(define *Elliot*
    '( (age . 40)
       (gender . male))
```

which have been used to create an unordered list (Mark Elliot Judith), how, using their ages in the merge sort

```
(merge-sort > '(20 40 30)) ---> (40 30 20)
```

can I output the ordered list

```
(Elliot Judith Mark)
```

Comment: @chris' answer is correct. And if you want to get the actual name. you must add it to the association list. And do something like `map get-name (merge-sort...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(merge-sort (lambda (a b)
              (define (get-age x)
                (cdr (assq 'age x)))
              (> (get-age a) (get-age b)))
            (list *Mark* *Judith* *Elliot*))
```

Comment: Your question and Chris' answer are a good example why Racket's `sort` has an optional `#:key` parameter: You can supply a function like `get-age` or `(compose cdr (curry assq 'age))`. It might be worthwhile to add a similar option to your `merge-sort`.

Comment: @GregHendershott I'd rather use Clojure's `#(cdr (assq 'age %))` syntax! https://gist.github.com/cky/8500450

Comment: Yes, although I think Haskell may win for composition and partial application syntax. :P  Anyway my point was that it's handy for a sort function to accept an optional "extract the key" function (however the user defines the function :)). That way, the user can supply just the "how to get the key" part, instead of the entire "how to compare two things" part.

Comment: Totally agree re supplying key accessor function.